# How to make "domain.com/index.php/path" work?

Tags: php, apache

Without using .htaccess, `index.php/path` works on server but not on local(*404 error*). So what is the configuration on apache for that to work.

Comment: The server is not using mod_rewrite for this?

Comment: I guess *you could* have a folder named `index.php`, no? (not too familiar with filesystems)

Comment: @caiosm1005 on joomla we use `index.php/contact` for `index.php?option=com_contact` if we don't use the help of `.htaccess`(url rewriting)

Comment: @caiosm1005 - possibly, but you'd still need rewrite in order to avoid having the extension (*.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enabling `AcceptPathInfo` in your Apache configuration. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo